# When do I need to use quotes in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

When do I need to surround strings in double quotes in PowerShell? Do I need all of these below?

```
& "$sendemail" -f "$sender" -t "$recipient" -u "$subject" -o message-file="$logpath" -s "$emailserver" -o tls=no
```

Comment: Quoting rules here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315325.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you need none.

- `$sendemail` is hopefully already a string so the call operator `&` would work on it (maybe anything else would get coerced into a string anyway).
- All other variables should be passed correctly-quoted as well:

  ```
  PS> $subject = 'subject string'
  PS> $recipient = 'recipient string'
  PS> $logpath = 'log path'
  PS> $emailserver = 'email server'
  PS> $recipient = 'recipient''s name'
  PS> $sender = 'sender''s name'
  PS> $sendemail = './echoargs.exe'
  PS> & $sendemail -f $sender -t $recipient -u $subject -o message-file=$logpath -s $emailserver -o tls=no
  arg 1: -f
  arg 2: sender's name
  arg 3: -t
  arg 4: recipient's name
  arg 5: -u
  arg 6: subject string
  arg 7: -o
  arg 8: message-file=log path
  arg 9: -s
  arg 10: email server
  arg 11: -o
  arg 12: tls=no
  ```

You would need quotes if you want to pass literal strings that contain special characters (e.g. shell operators or spaces) to a program, e.g.:

```
./echoargs 'some spaces and a | pipe'
```

If all your arguments either do not contain such things or are already contained in a string variable themselves you're good without quotes.

Answer (score 4):

There is [an explanation how to use apostrophes and quotes in PowerShell](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_quotes.htm). In your example you do not need them, as you do not expand variables, or perform concatenation.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Error 404 Not Found"*

Comment: @Akim Please update your response with an functional link. I recommend https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/when-to-quote-in-powershell/

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers thus far give just fragments of the answer to the full question *"When do you need quotes in PowerShell (and when needed, which kind do you use) ?"* Though one would naturally think the MSDN page [about_quoting_rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315325.aspx) would have a full answer, it does not. It mostly covers just string interpolation and here strings but does *not* address whether or if you actually need quotes.

The answer is perhaps a bit more complicated in PowerShell than other languages because PowerShell provides the flexibility of being both a scripting language and a shell language. PowerShell was designed to minimize the typing effort for the shell, as one would expect in a shell language, but at the same time, to be fully interoperable with PowerShell scripts.

I actually started to write up a detailed answer to post here, but it grew and grew until it morphed into an article-length story plus a pop-out wallchart (fragment shown below), all published on Simple-Talk.com. See [When to Quote in PowerShell](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/when-to-quote-in-powershell/).

[image]

Comment: The link still works (though [it redirects](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sysadmin/powershell/when-to-quote-in-powershell/) (now at `www.red-gate.com`)).